# How to enable gzip compression instead of brotli compression on OLS + DA?

Tags: compression, gzip, litespeed, brotli

I'm using Litespeed plugin for wordpress (From LiteSpeed Technologies), with a litespeed server, and despite what I do, it is not compressing javascript and css, and there's no option in the plugin for setting up "js & css" by the way. I already tried using other plugins, so I don't think the problem is the plugin, it's something in my server. I tried editing the following files `usr/local/lsws/conf/httpd-tuning.conf` and `/usr/local/directadmin/custombuild/configure/openlitespeed/conf/httpd-tuning.conf`

Changed the compression level, and yet I can't put this thing to compress. Yes, it is working, but it's only compressing text and html.

Even after changing the headers in the files from `text/*, application/x-javascript, application/xml, application/javascript, image/svg+xml,application/rss+x$`

to

`text/*, application/x-javascript, application/xml, application/javascript, text/html, text/css, text/plain, text/xml, text/x-js, text/js, text/javascript`

it still will not work.

Yes, I restart lightspeed every time I make changes, I can even see from the litespeed server administration that the new headers were applied. I believe it might be something else. I saw someone saying he said the same problem and his problem was the wildcard (besides the headers), but I don't know what that means.

Comment: LScache only caches dynamic page, like PHP ,  it doesn't cache any static resources

Comment: I'm using a litespeed server and I don't have any better alternative at my hosting, what should I do to compress js and css then?

Comment: yeah well , "compress" and "cache" are 2 different concept ,  compress should be default enabled already , what do you see on your JS/CSS file response header?

Comment: I've read like 3 tutorials and they always tell to check the response headers, but I can't find the responses that they suggest. I tried searching for litespeed in the headers, as suggested by one of litespeed tutorials, and I couldn't find anything. Can you check the headers and tell me? This is the url: https://lucrebem.com.br/evoluir/aprender-rapido-melhor/

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgsHk.png    https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGI78.png  , they are already gzip'ed

Comment: Are there anymore js/css files being compressed and what method you used to find the headers?

Comment: from what I see , all of them are gzip'ed  ,   chrome browser dev tool for header

Comment: I've noticed that a lot of js and css files are not compressed because they use brotli, since my vps uses a free version of litespeed server, I don't have access to the user interface of Open Litespeed software, I can only edit things through ssh. Do you know which file should I edit to change brotli settings? I've read that brotli already come enabled by default, ok, but I need to customize things.

Comment: brotil is generally considered as a better compression , why you want to force it to be gzip'ed  ?

Comment: I don't want to gzip brotli, I want to know how to set brotli compression.

Comment: what's your env ?   from the conf path it looks like DirectAdmin ?

Comment: I'm using Direct Admin, yes sir.

Comment: So? Any updates?

Answer (score 1):

For OLS, you can either enable gzip or brotli compression. Please refer to https://openlitespeed.org/kb/using-gzip-brotli-compression/. Since you are using OLS on DirectAdmin, you have no ability to modify the value by logging in to OLS admin console(That's because DA's implenmatation of splitting conf files, you will need to modify the server level or virtual host level directly by adding directive(brStaticCompressLevel   0) there. By the way, question title is better to change to: (not about caching at all, it is about )"How to enable gzip compression instead of brotli compression on OLS + DA" to avoid confusing.

Comment: I have made the changes as per your suggestion. But anyway, a lot of files are still not being compressed, even after making the changes.